# Change the color of directories in GNOME Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, ls

When I type `ls` in gnome terminal directories show up highlighted in green and the text is blue, making it very hard to read the directories.

I've tried *Edit → Preferences* and playing around with the color schemes, but the green highlight stays in place.

[image: screenshot of terminal showing green highlighting]

Comment: If changing the exact shade of the traditional 16 colors in gnome-terminal's preferences doesn't make a change, it means that the extended 256 or 16M colors are used here. Look around at the settings of the `ls` utility, i.e. the `LS_COLORS` env variable which is set from your `.bashrc` by `eval`'ing the output of `dircolors`...

Answer (score 1):

I know your post is old but I just went through this myself and thought I would share what I know.

My ls output was giving me the same thing but only on my partition where I store my data. That partition is an NTFS partition (some call it a "Windows type partition"). The ls command give different colors on a "Windows partition" and that's why I was getting the green highlights. I fixed my problem by adding a line to the bottom of my .bashrc file. The highlights went away and I was left with light blue for directories and green for files. Here's how I fixed it.

1. Shut down all open terminal emulators
2. Back up your .bashrc file (go to your home folder and press Ctrl-h to see your hidden / "." files and folders
3. Edit your .bashrc file
4. Add the following line to the bottom of .bashrc

export LS_COLORS='ow=01;36;40'

5. Save your .bashrc file. Some people say you have to run "source ~/.bashrc" to get your changes to take, but I never had to.
6. Open your terminal emulator and see if the highlights are gone

Hope that helps!

Comment: depending on if you use zsh you might have to add export LS_COLORS='ow=01;36;40' at the bottom of ~/.zshrc.